# iOS Twitter Framework: How to fetch (on the callback) last twitter account used to tweet?

Tags: ios, twitter, callback, account

Once a user has tweeted something, I need to differentiate which twitter account he used. Lets consider that the user would have 1 or several accounts configured on the phone.

I need tho know this after the tweet is successful, so the proper place would be the callback. I tried to fetch the accounts using ACAccountStore but it provides an array with all the accounts set up on the phone, not a clue about the last account used (not even the order of the array).

Does anyone knows if TWTweetComposeViewController remembers this account and, how to fetch it?

Thanks

My code:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet])
{
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetSheet = 
    [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"initial text"];
    [tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image]];

    // Callback
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        // if tweet was successful
        if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {

            // Get the accounts
            account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
            ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

            [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) 
             {
                 // if access granted I populate the array
                 if (granted == YES) {
                     NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                     ACAccount *account1 = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                     ACAccount *account2 = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:1];

                     NSString *username1 = account1.username;
                     NSString *username2 = account2.username;

                     // Always same order
                     NSLog(userName1);
                     NSLog(userName2);

                 }
             }];

            [self furtherMethodsInCaseOfSuccessfulTweet];


        } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"twit canceled");
        }
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    };


    [self presentModalViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES];

}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No tweet is possible on this device" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way.

Instead looking for the username on the insctance of TWTweetComposeViewController , lets use [GET users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) to qwery the names gathered by ACAccountStore.

> http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.xml?screen_name=username1,username2
>   (use json instead xml)

Parsing the results we can get the date/time of the last tweet of the users ("status" tag), and voila, we have the last account used.
In additiom, you can test the qwery results on the [console](https://dev.twitter.com/console).

Thanks to @theSeanCook